# How to do an infinite loop without blocking CPU

Tags: scala

How can I make this loop not using 100% CPU?

```
while(true){}
```

In the main thread, I do not want to quit, so I need to block the execution in the main thread, while allowing all other threads to continuously run. In Golang, there is an option:

```
select {}
```

which does not block CPU but also suspend main thread. How can I do this in Scala?

Comment: scala use different techniques for working with threads. So you may not even need a loop for that. You should describe a problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Also note that goroutines are co-routines, not threads, so there are different scheduling rules.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko I did describe the problem: `In the main thread, I do not want to quit, so I need to block the execution in the main thread, while allowing all other threads to continuously run.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest answer to your question might be:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

Await.result(Future.never, Duration.Inf) //semantic block
```

As the others have mentioned it might be better solutions for your problem( like [deferred](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/concurrency/deferred.html) from cats-io), but it's hard to tell more without more details.